# Duvidas em relação ao carregar combobox em c# com banco de dados MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

boa tarde, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso preencher uma combo box C# com dados de uma tabela em MySQL.
Estou fazendo uma aplicação para uma joalheria, e gostaria de saber como posso preencher a combo box de fornecedores através do seu código(ou id, como desejarem) preciso cadastrar seu código através do seu nome, esse é o método que eu fiz:

//parte para carregar o combobox de fornecedores

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; port=3306; User Id=root; database=dbbijus;");
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "select * from fornecedor";
        MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        cbFornecedor.DisplayMember = "NomeFant";
        cbFornecedor.ValueMember = "CodFornecedor";
        cbFornecedor.SelectedItem = "";
        cbFornecedor.Refresh();
        cbFornecedor.DataSource = dt;

        //parte para carregar o combobox de categorias

        com.CommandText = "select codcategoria,nomecategoria from categoria ";
        MySqlDataReader dred = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        dta.Load(dred);
        cbCategoria.DisplayMember = "NomeCategoria";
        cbCategoria.ValueMember = "CodCategoria";
        cbCategoria.SelectedValue = "";
        cbCategoria.DataSource = dta;
```

usando esse método eu ate consigo puxar o nome do fornecedor, mas só o nome,  o que eu preciso, como eu disse, e cadastrar o nome do fornecedor através do código

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: não, ainda tenho esse problema